# Is "crib bag" the Australian equivalent of "carryall" in AmE?

Tags: meaning, australian-english

I have seen bags labeled "crib bags" on Australian websites. I never really understand what they are precisely or whether "crib" refers to the material or the shape of the bag.

It seems the bags that fall under this category range from satchels, to tool bags, to carryalls (holdalls in BrE.) For example [this site](https://web.archive.org/web/20210506133257/http://www.cribbags.com/crib-bags/) specializes in them. What exactly is a crib bag? And what does "crib" refer to?

[image]

[image]
<sub>(source: [ruggedxtremes.com](https://www.ruggedxtremes.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/AFR030-3152-Edit_DE_LR-1-300x225.jpg))</sub>

Comment: Can you maybe find a definition of crib bag?  That might answer the question or at least help us to help you.

Comment: @DavidM Well, I posted the question exactly because I am not able to find a definition. Otherwise I would know what it is.

Comment: [Lexico: Crib](https://web.archive.org/web/20200805170455/https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/crib) Read entry number 6, might shed some light.

Comment: "Constructed from hard-wearing canvas with internal and external pockets for your **consumables**" From the description of the tool bag in your picture. They're saying it's a tool *and* lunch bag. The larger tool bag doesn't have the same distinction.

Comment: @DavidM So it seems the term originally refers to lunch bags and has evolved to include tool bags?

Comment: only seems to be the styles with an integrated lunch/snack bag ...

Comment: I posted a related question https://english.stackexchange.com/q/514402/59527

Comment: I'm Australian and don't recall having heard anyone use the term.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From Macquarie Dictionary

***[Crib:](https://www.macquariedictionary.com.au/resources/aus/word/map/search/word/crib/Far%20North%20Qld/)***

> 1. bag used to contain one's lunch items: *Did you bring your crib?*
> 2. the lunch so contained; *a packed lunch.*
> 3. lunch time.

[image]

CribBags.com -
Small Crib Bag, Black & Red

> As to its origin, the English Dialect Dictionary is silent. However, in all likelihood it is the same word as "crib" meaning: (originally) a barred receptacle for fodder, a baby's bed, a cabin, a hovel.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have the perfect answer for this old topic.

Crib bags are an essential element in the toolkit of every miner, assisting the easy and secure transportation of essential mining items from water bottles to crib containers to and from the mine site.

Source: https://gijaru.com/blogs/news/what-is-a-crib-bag-the-ultimate-mining-companion